# Plot 3 figures with common colorbar by using Basemap

Tags: python, projection, colorbar, matplotlib-basemap

I have been using this code to plot 3 figures with common colorbar:

```
grid_top = ImageGrid(fig, 211, nrows_ncols = (1, 3),
                     cbar_location = "right",     
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2) 

for n in xrange(3):
     im1 = grid_top[n].pcolor(data_top[n], 
                        interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=5)

plt.show()
```

I want to use Basemap to plot orthographic projection, which I define as:

```
m=Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=lon_0,lat_0=lat_0,resolution='l',
          llcrnrx=0.,‌​llcrnry=0.,urcrnrx=m1.urcrnrx/2.,urcrnry=m1.urcrnry/2.)
```

When, I change the code above as follow:

```
im1 = grid_top[n].m.pcolor(data_top[n], interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=5)
```

I get an error..

What do I have to change to make it works with Basemap ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a bit difficult to diagnose the specific error without seeing the error message you're getting, but I'll give it a go.

When you call `Basemap()` it draws the map to the currently active `Axes` instance, but when the axes are defined using `ImageGrid()` and then looped through none of them is ever active.  You can activate an existing Axes instance at any time using `plt.sca()` (set current axes).

To finalise the colorbar you need to call a `colorbar()` instance after you've actually plotted some data using `pcolor()` or `imshow()`.

Here's a working example of what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
data_top = []
for i in range(3):
    data_top.append(np.random.random((5,5)))


fig = plt.figure(1,(8.,8.))

grid_top = ImageGrid(fig, 211, nrows_ncols = (1, 3),
                     cbar_location = "right",
                     cbar_mode="single",
                     cbar_pad=.2)

for g, d in zip(grid_top,data_top):
    plt.sca(g)
    M = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=10.0,lat_0=50.0,resolution='l')
    M.drawcoastlines()
    M.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
    M.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
    I = M.imshow(d,vmin=0,vmax=1,interpolation="nearest")
grid_top.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(I)
```

[image: Some ugly maps, but you get the idea.]

Comment: This doesn’t guarantee that the colour bar will be wide enough, does it? What if the colour range on the first or second plot is wider than the last (which becomes I)?

Comment: @naught101 I just used the same hard-coded `vmin` and `vmax` for all three, as per the questioner's code.  You're right, that doesn't guarantee a sensible scale relative to the data, but it will be a consistent one across the three plots.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure consistency across the plots without hardcoding? Or is it basically a matter of getting the min/max manually?